# Applying color to a large number of duplicates (Bricks)

Tags: select

I modeled a brick. I made an array. I duplicated the array,added the courses to each other, then duplicated that,etc. I'm having trouble figuring how to color them all in one "click".

Answer (score 1):

Select all the objects you want to be the same color then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>  > *Make Links > Materials*.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the object with the desired material must be selected last, as it will be the active object. It is always the active object which will be referenced when linking to all the others.